# How do I get rid of this message in Vim when I'm working with golang files with Janus vim?

Tags: vim, go, vim-plugin, gvm

I use Vim to open up a hello.go file (using the nerdTree plugin included with [janus vim distro](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus)) and get "vim-go: could not find 'gotags'. Run :GoInstallBinaries to fix it.".  I'm using gvm.  I can get golang to run with gvm.  How do I install *GoInstallBinaries* with gvm to get rid of this message?  I'm pretty new to golang, so I'm just trying to get up and running.

Comment: You literally need to type (while is command mode) in vim, `:GoInstallBinaries`, then press enter.  The last time I did this there was at least one dependency that had moved and I needed to install it manually.

Comment: @sberry - consider converting your comment to an answer, because it appears to be one.

Comment: @sberry I created $GOPATH as export GOPATH="$HOME/workspace" and when I do :GoInstallBinaries I get "vim-go: go executable not found"

Answer (score 1):

Do what sberry says. In command-mode, hit : and type `GoInstallBinaries`, and hit enter. That should install everything.

Comment: I created $GOPATH as export GOPATH="$HOME/workspace" and when I do :GoInstallBinaries I get "vim-go: go executable not found"

Comment: You might not have Go installed properly in that case, or your `GOROOT` environment variable is not set.